# Parse Query exclude objects from a relation based on another relation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

Lets say I have default `User` class and a `job` class. In the job class I have 2 relational data columns `applicants` and `shortlisted` of `User` type. These 2 columns will have few data pointing to the same user. I mean one user might be in the applicants list and also in the shortlisted.

Now I want to show list of users applicants given the condition that those users are not part of shortlisted list. I was trying with `matchesKeyinQuery` but I guess i couldn't write the query properly. here's my snippet

```
const applicantsQuery = job.relation('applicants').query()
// do something in the middle so that it excludes users who also 
// belongs to shortlisted group
const data = await applicantsQuery.find()
```

Comment: " I was trying with matchesKeyinQuery but I guess i couldn't write the query properly. "  show us the code you tried?